# JQuery: Why won't the website open?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, setinterval

I'm sort of new to JQuery, but I'm practicing everyday. My goal is to open the link after the buttons have been clicked but the link doesn't seem to be opening. I'm trying to open the link inside the if statement so everything happens accordingly.

```
  window.setInterval(function(){ 
    if ($('#add-remove-buttons').find('.button').length > 0) {
        $('#size').val($('#size option').filter(function(ind, el) {
           return $(el).text() === 'Large';
        }).val());  
        $('#add-remove-buttons').find('.button').trigger('click'); 
        setTimeout(function() { 
          window.location.replace('http://myweblink'); 
         }, 900); 
        } 
   }, 100);
```

**EDIT (STILL NEED HELP)**

I've tried changing it but it doesn't load. I think it might be getting stuck in the 100ms loop. I put the function in a 100ms loop so it can detect `if ($('#add-remove-buttons').find('.button').length > 0)` I also just realized that after the user clicks the button, this html automatically appears:

```
<fieldset id="add-remove-buttons"><input class="button remove" name="commit" value="remove" type="submit"><a href="/shop" class="button continue">keep shopping</a></fieldset>
```

This means that the if statement : if `($('#add-remove-buttons').find('.button').length > 0)` from my code, becomes false and the code for changing the URL doesn't run. Is there a way to detect the presence of the html code above like the if statement that became false? After I figure that out, I can put the `window.location.href = "http://myweblink";` and then get it to work!

Comment: Add your markup and please explain what exactly are you trying to achieve

Comment: Why are you repeating all of these in an interval of 100ms??? Sorry but your code is seriously odd. Also, why you even need to change the browser's location after 900ms?

Comment: @BenBozorg I know, it's meant to be super fast. But i need it to go 900ms after the buttons have been clicked.

Comment: You are missing the complete web address, please see my answer. Thanks

Comment: can you paste your html code n js in a fiddle

Comment: @Shivkumar Updated the issue!

Comment: I don't get interval part. Jquery have simple `.click` function, and its detecting every click on a given element.  You are complicating instead of simple check if all elements are clicked and then redirect.

Answer (score 1):

And in your code it is missing the complete web address.

Use

```
 window.location.replace('http://myweblink.com');
```

Instead

```
 window.location.replace('http://myweblink');
```

To redirect,jQuery is not necessary, and window.location.replace(...) will best simulate an HTTP redirect.

It is better than using window.location.href =, because replace() does not keep the originating page in the session history, meaning the user won't get stuck in a never-ending back-button fiasco. If you want to simulate someone clicking on a link, use location.href. If you want to simulate an HTTP redirect, use location.replace.

For example:

```
// similar behavior as an HTTP redirect
window.location.replace("http://stackoverflow.com");

// similar behavior as clicking on a link
window.location.href = "http://stackoverflow.com";
```

You can read the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/503093/how-do-i-redirect-to-another-page-in-jquery).

Answer (score 0):

**Try**
`window.location.href = "http://your.wesite.com";`
**This will replace your address bar.**

Comment: I tried this, it's just acting the same way as before. It gets stuck and doesn't load.

Comment: @MGames Try open that website in other tab directly. Check whether it is working fine or not.

Comment: I've tried that but for some reason when I run a location.reload() it works but it's glitchy.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using jQuery, just use **$(location).attr('href',url)**;.

window.location.href seems to have inconstant behavior in some browsers, in fact, it flat out doesn't work in my version of Firefox.

Comment: Updated the issue

Comment: @MGames The issue is with setInterval(function(){ 900} . can you explain why are you using it. what you what to achieve through it.